# How to give path to txt to read from in java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm reading a txt with BuffererReader and I wonder how to give the path to my txt in BufferedReader's argument.

```
BufferedReader input = new Bufferedreader(
    new FileReader(D:VI.félév\Prog gyak\Project\proba.txt));
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: change this FileReader(D:VI.félév\Prog gyak\Project\proba.txt)
to FileReader("D:\\VI.félév\\Prog gyak\\Project\\proba.txt")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
new Filereader( .. )
```

should be

```
new FileReader( .. )
```

And the path has to look like:

```
new FileReader("D:\\directory\\proba.txt");
```

You need an additional `\` as escape character

Answer (score 0):

Full Working Example with `try..catch` if problem any occur.

```
     BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\directory\\proba.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```